# выявление наилучшей регрессионной модели в r

Tags: r, статистика

здравствуйте, подскажите, пожалуйста, как в R написать , чтобы из уравнения y~x был выявленен наилучший  полином ( например , чтобы он вывел результат, что y~x ^4  + x  является наилушим описанием модели)

Answer (score 2):

"Наилучшего полинома" не бывает.

Во-первых, вы не определили, что такое "наилучший". Если понимать это как такой, который дает наименьшую ошибку на обучающей выборке, то по определению наилучшим будет полином степени N-1, где N -  количество точек (математика, школьный курс, класс -  наверное 9 или 10). Что нас, как правило, не устраивает в принципе.
Задача регрессии как раз и предполагает, что вы должны выбрать степень полинома (или говорят - семейство полиномов) сами, а качество проверить не только на обучающей, а на тестовой выборке. 
Другими словами, алгорим выбора "лучшего" полинома примерно таков:

1. Перебираем ВЫБРАННЫЕ НАМИ виды зависимости(семейства полиномов), строим моделИ, (причем - в рамках выбранного семейства полиномов МНК - сам найдет "лучший" с его точки зрения набор коэффициентов, лассо-регрессия - свой, и скорее всего - другой,  ридж-регрессия - свой и т.д).
2. Затем проверяем точность моделей на тестовой выборке. Выбираем ту, которая дала минимум ошибки. Причем не факт, что на другой тестовой выборке лучшей окажется та-же модель.

Замечу, что я еще не сказал ничего о мере ошибки модели. Они тоже бывают разными (да, наиболее распространенная - сумма квадратов ошибок, но это не единственный возможный вариант) и в результате дают свое множество "наилучших" решений.

Итог. Выбор "лучшей" модели - это задача неформализованная и требующая умственных усилий исследователя.
Вот как-то так.